# Getting Error 404, application not found error when deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Java Application, using Eclipse plugin. When I try to upload, I get error:

> com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=my_appname&version=1&
>   404 Not Found
>   This application does not exist (app_id=u'my_appname').

Here, `my_appname` is the application id from my Google App Engine account. I have already checked the contents of `appengine-web.xml`, it looks fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>my_appname</application>
  <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix my application?

Comment: Did you actually create "my_appname" in the Google App Engine Console?

Answer (score 1):

Got the exact same thing.

The above suggestion was correct.  It was a permissions problem.

Go to the Google App Engine Console, open the app.  Look down the left side, open Permissions link.  I have two domain email accounts that I use.  One was shown as having 'Owner' role with respect to the app.  The other was not listed!  The problem occurred because I was logged into Eclipse using the unauthorized (missing) email account.

Simply make sure you are logged into Eclipse GAE using an account that has 'Owner' or 'Developer' role and that will solve it.

Comment: Same problem here, but from command console with maven, not eclipse. The upload worked after I added the Owner permission to the right email account in Google App Engine Console and I accepted the invitation (I received an email containing the invitation link).

Answer (score 1):

Just to leave documented to others, I had similar issue while running it from command line. The first attempt was with the email I hold for other apps, so it did not find the app I was trying to update. Then, even forcing the option --email, still no luck.

It turned out that once the authentication is cached (with cookies), it will use it by default even if you force --email with a different credential. So, the solution is to add the option --no_cookies, which removes the previously stored cookie and prompts for the password of the email.

```
# assuming you are in the root directory of your app, 
# and GAE tools are in yout $PATH
$ appcfg.py --email {your email here} --no_cookies .
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem , for solution try it

1->your application Id must be same as your application name in your google app engine account.

2->version must not be in dot(.) format.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:** This happens when you had changed your application name in "build.properties" file but its not updated into "appengine-web.xml" file.

**Solution:** Please go ahead and change application name in "appengine-web.xml" manually.

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>Modified_application_name</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: I have the same issue.Do I need to put project_ud for Modified _application_name ?

Answer (score 0):

try to check the permissions. Go to App Engine Console > Administration > Permissions > setup your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A common error is forget to edit the web.xml file, you must to specific the inicial web page.

```
<!-- Default page to serve --> <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Default.html</welcome-file>  </welcome-file-list>
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure - but I think even errors in code of the web-pages themselves might lead to that...