# This application does not exist (app_id=u'google.com:nbsocialmetrics')

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I know others have posted similar issues but after trying their solutions I think this is a different problem.

I'm trying to get a multi-module application functioning for Google App Engine.  I'm developing it from this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java).

I was able to get my application running successfully in the development server but I encountered the following error when I tried to upload to Google App Engine with the command `mvn appengine:update`:

```
Error Details:
Nov 05, 2014 10:23:51 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: /guestbook.jsp

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=nbsocialmetrics-frontend&app_id=google.com%3Anbsocialmetrics&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'google.com:nbsocialmetrics').

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=nbsocialmetrics-frontend&app_id=google.com%3Anbsocialmetrics&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'google.com:nbsocialmetrics').

Please see the logs [/var/folders/dp/v_lw6kqx16bf7743hs5t9phc0000gn/T/appcfg8240676105577823958.log] for further information.
```

I've listed a bunch of references to similar problems but here is a summary of what they say and why it didn't work for me:

1] Permissions - Make sure you have permission to upload code to this google account.  I verified by going to http://appengine.google.com, clicking my app, `nbsocialmetrics`, and clicking permissions.  There it lists the correct Google account and it says the Role is owner.

2] Delete cookies - To ensure my credentials hadn't been cached, I deleted the file ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java (I'm on a Mac).  Apparently this file used be called .appcfg_cookies which you'll see in the references I've listed below.

3] `appcfg.sh --no_cookies` - Some people suggested another approach beside #2 above: call c.  However, I'm using `mvn appengine:update` and it would take a lot of work to figure out how `mvn appengine:update` and `mvn appengine:update` relate to each other.  So I didn't try this.

References to similar problems whose suggestions did not work:

- [GAE/J This application does not exist (app_id=u'application-id')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172576/gae-j-this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-uapplication-id)
- [Getting Error 404, application not found error when deploying to Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646461/getting-error-404-application-not-found-error-when-deploying-to-google-app-engi)
- [This application does not exist (app_id=xxx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx)
- [This application does not exist - GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947098/this-application-does-not-exist-gae)
- http://juplo.de/log-out-from-wrong-account-with-maven-appengine-plugin/
- http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6014266/solved-unable-to-deploy-my-app-this-application-does-not-exist
- https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5331
- http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/08/solved-this-application-does-not-exist.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed how the error I got was different from other reports of this issue.  Notice the prefix `google.com:` in the error message I received:

```
This application does not exist (app_id=u'google.com:nbsocialmetrics').
```

This prefix wasn't in the other reports of this problem.  So I tracked that prefix down to the file I was modeling after: [appengine-application.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/blob/master/appengine-modules-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/appengine-application.xml).

My solution was to remove the prefix from my appengine-application.xml so it now reads this:

```
<application>nbsocialmetrics</application>
```

Instead of:

```
<application>google.com:nbsocialmetrics</application>
```

I have no idea why that prefix was in the sample code.

Comment: There is also a "u" before my app_id when I encountered the same problem as you. The problem for me is that there is no colon inside my app_id. So I have no chance to solve the problem the same way as you. But sbahn's answer is correct for me. So I marked his answer as useful.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using windows,
you can try after delete this file

> > C:/Users/{username}/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java
> >     (maybe somthing like this file.)

I'm using eclipse maven plugins to build and packaging.
By this way i could fix it !

References : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

Comment: Thanks for the solution @sbahn, if I get a chance to verify it someday I'll accept your answer instead of mine.

Comment: Where to find this file in Mac?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal
It would be helpful. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18923?locale=en_US