# Google app engine This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320')

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a simple Guestbook app made with Google App Engine with the command

```
    mvn appengine:update
```

but I get the error

```
    This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320')
```

I have tried to delete .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java and update again, it simply redirect me again to the token page and when I paste it and press enter I get always the same error...

It follows the full log

```
nov 01, 2015 10:16:51 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader rea
dConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Marco\GAE\guestbook\target\guestbook-1.0-S
NAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\datastore-indexes-auto.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
nov 01, 2015 10:16:51 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getre
sourcelimits?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #0
nov 01, 2015 10:16:51 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getre
sourcelimits?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #1
nov 01, 2015 10:16:52 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getre
sourcelimits?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #2
nov 01, 2015 10:16:52 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getre
sourcelimits?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #3
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg803610
7022033767950.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.
warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
  Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a poli
cy for implicit compilation.
1 warning
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
nov 01, 2015 10:16:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/creat
e?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #0
nov 01, 2015 10:16:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/creat
e?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #1
nov 01, 2015 10:16:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/creat
e?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #2
nov 01, 2015 10:16:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnecti
on send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/creat
e?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').
This is try #3

Error Details:
nov 01, 2015 10:16:55 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \guestbook.jsp


com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://
appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/app
version/create?app_id=111320&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'111320').

Please see the logs [C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8922461300350626057
.log] for further information.
```

Comment: It's quite unlikely that your appid is actually numeric. It should be the part before ".appspot.com". Please check your pom.xml and src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml and put in the correct app id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This application does not exist (app\_id=u'google.com:nbsocialmetrics')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766323/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-ugoogle-comnbsocialmetrics)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed,
wrong app id in my case.
Full ID of my app is "rising-symbol-111320" so I changed it manually in pom.xml

```
<app.id>rising-symbol-111320</app.id>
```